# Setting up Huzzah ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to set up a Huzzah ESP8266 and can not get it to work. I have scoured the internet for help and to no avail. I have the board loaded with a baud rate of 115200 and am transmitting at  80 MHz. When I try and upload the sketch it successfully uploads and after a second or two it sends me this error.

> Sketch uses 222,209 bytes (21%) of program storage space. Maximum is
>   1,044,464 bytes. Global variables use 31,576 bytes (38%) of dynamic
>   memory, leaving 50,344 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81,920
>   bytes.
>
> warning: espcomm_sync failed
>
> error: espcomm_open failed
>
> error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
>
> error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

Here is my code:

```
 void setup() {
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
 void loop() {
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the    voltage level
                                // but actually the LED is on; this is     because 
                                // it is acive low on the ESP-01)
delay(1000);                      // Wait for a second
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
delay(2000);                      // Wait for two seconds (to demonstrate the active low LED)
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or can anyone help me out.

Comment: Did you select the port of your ESP8266 in the **Tools > Port** menu? Please select **File > Preferences > Show verbose output during > upload**, upload the sketch, and then update the error message in your question with the full verbose output.

Comment: espcomm error messages usually mean that your sketch is -not- uploaded correctly. Are you sure you selected "Adafruit HUZZAH ESP8266" in the arduino IDE? It should be in the list.

Comment: Also, does the HUZZAH actually have a usb to serial chip on the board, or do you need an external one? If so whichone are you using? Some FTDI? I can't check myself atm., behind a firewall :)

Comment: Have you contacted your seller/supplier? Adafruit actually has very good support and they sure know their hardware and possible faults.

Answer (score 1):

If you´re working with a development board, they (usually) come with tow buttons: *Reset* and *Flash*. If this is the case **before** start to upload your code you **must** press the *Flash* button, this error is common when the *Flash* button it's not pressed.

If you're working with an ESP8266-01 (this is the "naked" esp8266) you **must** read this tutorials: [GreatScott vid on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QZkCQSHnko), and for the connections: a good [Hackster.io tutorial](https://www.hackster.io/rayburne/esp8266-01-using-arduino-ide-67a124).

Hope you can make it run!!!

Answer (score 0):

When using a serial cable (4 wires, only works on windows), you need to press the 2 buttons in the sequence described here (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah-esp8266-breakout/using-arduino-ide): gpio0 down, reset down, reset up, gpio0 up. The red led should be dim now. This means the huzzah is ready to bootload.